# Showing 1 million rows in a browser

Tags: database, hibernate, design-patterns, web, derby

Our Utilty has one single table, and it has 10 million to 50 million rows, There may be a case we need to show 50 million rows in a single page html client page, To show the rows in browser we use jQuery in UI.

To retrieve rows we use Hibernate and use Spring for MVC. I am looking for best practice in retrieving the rows and showing in UI. Should I retrieve a bulk of thousands rows or two thousand rows  in Hibernate and buffer to Web Client or a best practice is there ?

Comment: Why is this tagged 'Derby'?

Comment: we used apache derby as our database server

Answer (score 11):

The best practice is not to do this. It will explode the browser memory and rendering engine, and will take too much time to load.

Add a search form to your webapp, make the end user search for what he's interested about, and only display the N first search results, just like Google does.

Nobody is able to do anything meaningful with 50 million rows without searching anyway.

Answer (score 4):

i think you should use scroll pagination (when user reaches to almost bottom of page makes ajax call and load data).

Just for example quick google [example](http://www.fieg.nl/infinite-ajax-scroll-a-jquery-plugin) & [demo](http://www.fieg.nl/ias-demo)

and if your data is tabular then you can use [jQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/paging/scrollbar/default.php)

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions!

Comment: Do not forget to do Lazy loading or Cache at the backend for performance...!!

Answer (score 1):

Handling a larger quantity of data in an application must be done via virtualization. While it's true that the user will be overwhelmed by millions of records, it's not exactly true that they can't do stuff with it, nor that such quantities of data are unfathomable.

In practice and depending on what you're doing you'll note that this limit crops up on you with just thousands of records. Which frankly is very little data. Data centric apps just need a different approach, altogether, if they are going to work in a browser and perform well.

The way we do this is quite simple but not all that straightforward.

It helps to decide on a fixed height, because you will need to know the max height of a scrollable container. You then render into this container the subset of records that can be visible at any given moment and position them accordingly (based on scroll events). There are more or less efficient ways of doing this.

The end goal remains the same. You basically need to cull everything which isn't directly visible on screen in such a way that the browser isn't paying the cost of memory and layout logic for the app to be responsive. This is common practice in game development, only the world that is visible right now on screen is ever present at any given moment. So that's what you need to do to get large quantities of stuff to behave well.

In the context of a browser, anything which attributes to memory use and layout/render cost needs to go away if it's isn't absolutely vital.

You can also stagger and smear recalculations so that you don't incur the cost of whatever is causing the app to degrade on every small update. The user can afford to wait 1 second, if the apps remains responsive.

Answer (score 0):

(disclaimer I am the maintainer)
I have made a grid for this purpose that can render unlimited rows, only RAM can stop you. It initializes and shows first rows within 2ms on any row size, and runs 60fps while scrolling even on old laptops.

https://github.com/gabrielpetersson/fast-grid

Demo:
https://fast-grid.vercel.app/